# How to modify the default B5 print format for document notes?

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I have LibreOffice 5.3.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to print the document notes of my Impress document. When in the 'Print' box I select document 'Notes', the default page format is then modified to B5 which my printer does not have and that generates an error on the printer. How could I modify the default page format? I do not see a 'Page' entry in the page menu.

Comment: quick hack : modify the ruler to mak the whole doc occupy 50% (or less) max, try different values see if when printing Libreoffice no longer needs to change page type since it still fits on A4.

Comment: didnt undestood your hack, but this gave me the solution, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page format is accessible when in 'Notes' mode by the menu 'Slide', 'Slide properties' and then selecting A4 as the paper format. This is also accessible by a right click and then 'Slide properties'